# How to Increase the Number of Levels in a Pallet Rack Using AnyLogic's Parameter?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

My goal is to use a **slider** to increase or decrease the number of levels in a pallet rack.

**But there is no option in pallet rack properties to add a parameter or a variable.**

[image]

How can I achieve that? Kindly let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can change this value with the function `palletRack.setNumberOfLevels(nLevel)` but before the initialization of simulation markup element.

For example you can use it in 'Before simulation run' section in `Simulation Experiment` `root.palletRack.setNumberOfLevels(myIntVar);`

Comment: In my palletRack the number of levels set is 1, then i make a function on Main `palletRack.setNumberOfLevels(4)` but the level of palletRack do not change, its still one.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, you cannot change this value inside the main just before its initialization.